# Magento2 : How to show as separate lines for each discount on cart page?

Tags: magento2, coupon

In magento2 - Anybody please let me know how we can separate the discounts on cart page on different lines.
**For example: I have a basic discount $5 for all products and I'm applying a promotion code which gives $10 discount.
Currently magento2 showing this discount as:**

**Discount | promotion-code $15**

But I need to display it as:

**Discount | promotion-name(Promotion without discount code) $5**

**Discount | promotion-code(Promotion with discount code) $10**